# Play 2 : play.libs.WS VS 3rd party client library for async processing

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

My Java Play2 app is calling some external web services to get data through a synchronous 3rd party client library. For this app I need high traffic and scalability.

The play documentation says :

> Cases when your code may block include:
>   Using REST/WebService APIs through a **3rd party client library** (ie, not
>   using Play’s asynchronous WS API)
>   [...]
>
> Note that you may be tempted to therefore wrap your blocking code in Futures. **This does not make it non blocking**, it just means the blocking will happen in a different thread[...]
>
> In contrast, the following types of IO do not block:
>   **The Play WS API**, ...

In a Play2 Java app, it's not really useful to use promises to make things asynchronous because the default play pool is used for Futur tasks. As a result, using a lot of Futur will result as the same thing as using only synchronous calls with a large default thread pool : roughly same number of threads in the same pool.

So my questions are :

- is the play.libs.WS API in the the Java API really asynchronous (not blocking any thread in the play default pool) ?
- should I always use it rather than my 3rd party client library if I want high traffic and scalability
- what is the thread pool used by play.libs.WS API and should I increase its size if my application do a lot a WS calls?
- is there a way to be as async as the play.libs.WS API, by wrapping the 3rd party synchronous client in futures?

Thanks a lot

Loïc

Comment: Looking at the code, play.libs.WS seems to use the Netty pool (using a AsyncCompletionHandler<com.ning.http.client.Response>)
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Guillaume Bort said on the Play mailing list, play.libs.WS API "has its own thread-pool, managed by the AsyncHttp library itself, but since it uses NIO under the hood, it doesn't matter as it is basically really non-blocking."

So it should be used as often as possible.